# Proving a Summation using induction

Tags: summation, induction

I am trying to prove the following summation inequality via induction:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\geq 2\sqrt{n+1}-2$$

I know that first I must check base case, which is $n=1$.
$$\frac{1}{1}=1\geq2\sqrt{2}-2=0.8...$$
which checks out. Next, I assume that the inequality holds for $k$. Thus, for $k+1$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\geq 2\sqrt{k+1}-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$
Here I recognized, that the first $k$ terms correspond to the case that I assume is true. Now I need to manipulate this epxression algebraically to find:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\geq 2\sqrt{k+2}-2$$
However, when I manipulate the expression I got for $k+1$:
$$2\sqrt{k+1}-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{2(k+1)+1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-2$$
From this point I have been unable to make progress. I feel like I am very close to the answer, yet I seem to be unable to manipulate the expression in the correct way.
What could I do next?

Answer (score 1):

From your last step, it suffices to show $2(k+1)+1 \ge 2\sqrt{(k+2)(k+1)}$, which will give you the desired result.
To check this inequality, it may help to square both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sqrt {k+2}+\sqrt {k+1} >2\sqrt {k+1}$ so $\frac 1 {\sqrt {k+1}} >\frac  2 {\sqrt {k+1}+\sqrt {k+2}} =2 (\sqrt {k+2}-\sqrt {k+1}) $. Can you use this to go from $k$ to $k+1$?

Comment: While I understand the way you write it, I don't see how I would get from what I had to the hint you gave. And even if I did, don't I have to prove somehow the inequality you hinted? Or is it something considered trivial?

Comment: $k+2 >k+1$ and that gives the first inequality in my answer.  @NickHeumann