# $\sum _{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n+\ 1}-2$

Tags: induction

How to prove that

$\sum _{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n+\ 1}-2$

$n\ \varepsilon \ \mathbb{N}$

is valid? Using induction.

n=1

$\sum _{j=1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{1+\ 1}-2$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{1+\ 1}-2$

$1\ge 2\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)$

which is true

now n+1

$\sum _{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n+1+\ 1}-2$

$\sum _{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}+\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ \ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n+2}-2$

now edit left side

$\sum _{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}+\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ $\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n+\ 1}-2\ +\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

how get this to $2\cdot \sqrt{n+2}-2$ ?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515400/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141039/42969 or  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3898331/42969.

Comment: It's not clear to me that "using induction" is part of what you are asking for, or just an explanation of how you tried to prove it. Perhaps an easier way to prove it is to compare the summation with the definite integral of 1/√x over the range 1 ≤ x ≤ n+1.